# Wordpress Posts Are Showing In Reverse Order (oldest first)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am helping a friend with their Wordpress site and all of their blog posts are showing in reverse order (oldest first). I haven't found any plugins responsible and haven't identified any code that was added. I also tried adding the code

````
//function to modify default WordPress query
function wpb_custom_query( $query ) {

// Make sure we only modify the main query on the homepage  
    if( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() && $query->is_home() ) {

        // Set parameters to modify the query
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
        $query->set( 'suppress_filters', 'true' );
    }
}

// Hook our custom query function to the pre_get_posts 
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpb_custom_query' );```

They are using the theme RT-Theme 18

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?
````

Comment: Have you disabled the theme and plugins? Check what is causing it by reenabling them one-by-one. Your function above looks fine.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet.  Thank you Fraggley.  I will check that!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @fraggley, start off by disabling all plugins and setting the theme to TwentyTwenty (the default theme). The RT-Theme 18 also exhibits similar behaviour in their [demo](https://rttheme18.demo-rt.com/blog/) with no obvious setting to change this behaviour. If you aren't already, ensure you're making customisations in a child-theme. Without creating a new function, try using a standard loop to start off to see whether the order is still incorrect.

```
<?php

get_header();

if ( have_posts() ) : 

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        the_content();

    endwhile;

else :

    _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'textdomain' );

endif;

get_footer();

?>
```

This would typically be placed in your home.php or index.php at the root of your child theme. WordPress provides good documentation on this in their [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#home-page-display). You can determine this by checking which file the original code occurs in the parent theme. So if the loop occurs in the parent theme home.php, create a file called home.php in the same relative location on your child theme. More documentation on this [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

Comment: Thank you for the tips terfex. I hadn't noticed that the theme demo has the same issue with their blog posts. Excellent find!  I emailed them to ask if they had any suggestions.  As to the code you provided, where would I put that in the file? I assume in theme functions but I am new to PHP so not sure how to implement that. When I tried to put it in the first line threw an error.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The above code would typically go in your index.php or home.php file. I've updated my answer above to provide better clarification. Can you please provide a snippet of the loop from the parent theme if possible?